# WPF app loads a plugin with a window well first time, but fails to show the window second time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.8

The app implements plugins by loading assemblies. The plugins can be loaded multiple times and it works pretty straightforwardly, until I show a window from within the plugin. It works for a first time, but does not open the window second time.

### Example

#### Host app

Host.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>default</LangVersion>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <StartupObject>Host.MainModule</StartupObject>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="MainModule.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

MainModule.xaml

```xml
<Application x:Class="Host.MainModule"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"/>
```

MainModule.xaml.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;

namespace Host;

public partial class MainModule
{
  protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
  {
      base.OnStartup(e);

      LoadAndRun(@"..\..\..\..\..\Service\bin\x64\Debug\net48\Service.dll");
      LoadAndRun(@"..\..\..\..\..\Service\bin\x64\Debug\net48\Service.dll");

      MessageBox.Show("ok");

      Shutdown();
  }

  private static void LoadAndRun(string path) {
    var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(folder, path)));
    var provider = assembly.GetType("Service.Provider");
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(provider);
    var method = provider.GetMethod("Run");
    method.Invoke(instance, null);
  }
}
```

### Service library

Service.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>default</LangVersion>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>library</OutputType>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Provider.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

namespace Service;

public sealed class Provider {
  public void Run() {
    var form = new Form();
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    form.ShowDialog();
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(Provider)}.{nameof(Run)}: form was opened for {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
  }
}
```

Form.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="Service.Form"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Form"
        Height="400" Width="200">
</Window>
```

Form.xaml.cs

```cs
using System;

namespace Service;

public partial class Form {
  public Form() {
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(Form)}.{nameof(Form)}: start");
    InitializeComponent();
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(Form)}.{nameof(Form)}: done");
  }
}
```

### Run

When started, the app shows the Form once and then a message box.

The console output is:

```
Form.Form: start
Form.Form: done
Provider.Run: form was opened for 1159 ms
Form.Form: start
Form.Form: done
Provider.Run: form was opened for 0 ms
```

As you can see, the form starts for the second time, no exceptions, but closes immediately.

I'll appreciate you help on this matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check [Application.ShutdownMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.shutdownmode). The default is OnLastWindowClose and thus your application will shut down when the first Window  closes. If you want to keep the application running, change it to OnExplicitShutdown.

It has nothing to do with loading a Window from a separate assembly.